# Can't change empty index name in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have over 100 csv files, all contain a table with the same indexes and indentical length. I am able to concat them into a single dataframe and save as csv.

```
print(df)

         a   b   c   d
0    1   5   1   7   7
1    2   3   1   7   7
2    3   2   2   8   7
3    1   6   1   7   6
```

I want to add a name to the now blank 'initial index' but every solution I find doesn't work...
I've tried:

```
df.rename(columns={'': 'initial'}, inplace=True)
df1 = df.rename(columns={'': 'initial'})
df1 = df.set_index('initial')
df1 = df.rename_axis("initial")
```

Header printout as is:

```
print([*df])
[' a b c d']
```

I am using Python 3.7.3

**Edit**

Thanks for the feedback. Both Joe Ferndz and icecity96 solutions work. They didn't initially only because .csv file columns were seperated with spaces not comma's, therefore the DataFrame has seen only one column. Problem gone away after adding **delim_whitespace=True**

```
pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Output before:

```
print(*df)
[' a b c d']
```

Output after:

```
print([*df])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like the output you'd get from `print([*df])`, unless somehow you have a single column with the label `' a b c d'` and everything happened to pretty print perfectly. What is `df.index`?

Comment: How many columns do you have in your original dataframe. I think 5 or is it 1?

Comment: can you do print (list(df)) and tell me what it shows? Does it print ['','a','b','c','d'] ?

Comment: After finding my mistake all works as intended

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df.rename({df.columns[0]: 'initial'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> print([*df])
['', 'a', 'b']
>>> df.rename({df.columns[0]: 'initial'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
>>> print([*df])
['initial', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename the columns, can't you just do something as simple as this please?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'' :[1,2,3,4],
                   'A':['A','B','C','D'],
                   'Z':[True, False, False, True]})
print(df)

df.columns = ['New','A','B']

print(df)
```

Here the first column got renamed as 'New' and also renamed column Z as B

Output is:

**Before:**

```
      A      Z
0  1  A   True
1  2  B  False
2  3  C  False
3  4  D   True
```

**After:**

```
   New  A      B
0    1  A   True
1    2  B  False
2    3  C  False
3    4  D   True
```